# Python XML processing after a specific comment

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have an automated process that keeps an XML file up to date based on an external data source.   This XML file can also be modified by users, their manual changes need to be maintained.

```
<Nodes>
    <!-- User added data goes here -->
    <Node name="1">Data Data Data</Node>
    <Node name="2">Data Data Data</Node>
    <Node name="3">Data Data Data</Node>

    <!-- AUTOMATEDSTUFF -->
    <!-- User, do not modify nodes below this line. -->
    <Node name="4">Data Data Data</Node>
    <Node name="5">Data Data Data</Node>
    <Node name="6">Data Data Data</Node>

</Nodes>
```

On every update of the file, I want to blow away all of the nodes previously added by my automation.  This is everything below the:

```
<!-- AUTOMATEDSTUFF -->
```

Right now I'm reading all Nodes in Python like this:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse(filename)
nodesSection = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Nodes')[0]
for child in nodesSection.childNodes:
    .....
```

How do I only start looking for Nodes after encountering my comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XML, comments are comments, and can be rightfully stripped out of the document in any stage of processing. You should adapt your program to add a special attribute, like

```
<Nodes>
    <!-- User added data goes here -->
    <Node name="1">Data Data Data</Node>
    <Node name="2">Data Data Data</Node>
    <Node name="3">Data Data Data</Node>

    <!-- User, do not modify nodes below this line. -->
    <Node name="4" from="autogenerated">Data Data Data</Node>
    <Node name="5" from="autogenerated">Data Data Data</Node>
    <Node name="6" from="autogenerated">Data Data Data</Node>
</Nodes>
```

Then, you can simply filter out all nodes with the property `from="autogenerated"`.

---

However, if you really want to detect comments (and as mentioned above, *that's a bad idea*), simply check all children of `<Node>`:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse(filename)
nodes = xmldoc.documentElement.childNodes
commentIdx = next(i for i,n in enumerate(nodes) if
                n.nodeType == n.COMMENT_ELEMENT and n.data == ' AUTOMATEDSTUFF ')
automatedNodes = nodes[commentIdx+1:]
print(automatedNodes) # or do something else with them
```